# Angular 2 : Error with directives and routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular 2 and I am experiencing difficulties to achieve a really simple app : a basic router with 1 component.

I've read the getting started / tutorial and watched lessons at egghead.io.

First, there is my code :

```
// src/app.ts
import { bootstrap } from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from "angular2/router";
import { AppComponent } from "./components/index";

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS
]);


// src/components/app.component.ts
import { Component } from "angular2/core";
import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from "angular2/router";
import { HomeComponent, NavComponent } from "./index";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-view',
    directives: [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, NavComponent ],
    template: `
        <h1>App</h1>
        <nav-cmp></nav-cmp>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `
})
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/home',    name: 'Home',   component: HomeComponent }
])
export class AppComponent { }


// src/components/nav.component.ts
import { Component } from "angular2/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'nav-cmp',
    template: `
        <nav>
            <a [routerLink]="['Home']">Home</a>
        </nav>
    `
})
export class NavComponent { }


// src/components/home.component.ts
import { Component } from "angular2/core";

@Component({
    template: `<h2>Home.</h2>`
})
export class HomeComponent { }


// src/components/index.ts
export { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
export { NavComponent } from "./nav.component";
export { HomeComponent } from "./home.component";
```

and the index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
        System.config({
            packages: {
                build: {
                    format: 'register',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            }
        });
        System.import('build/app')
                .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <app-view>Loading...</app-view>

</body>
</html>
```

The error message is :
**Unexpected directive value 'undefined' on the View of component 'AppComponent'**

I don't really get what I've changed but one hour ago, it was *Route config should contain exactly one "component", "loader", or "redirectTo" property.**

I really don't get what I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT : `package.json` and `tsconfig.json` added.**
package.json :

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run http\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc -p .",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w -p .",
    "wp:w": "webpack --watch",
    "lite": "nano-server",
    "http": "http-server -p 3000 -a 127.0.0.1 -o",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@ngrx/store": "^1.3.3",
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.9",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.24",
    "zone.js": "0.5.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "sass-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.7",
    "typings": "^0.7.5",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "sourceRoot": "./src/",
    "rootDir": "./src/"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

**EDIT 2 : project's structure :**

```
project/
├── build/
│   └── all my .js & .map
├── docs/
│   └── some usefull .md files :)
├── node_modules/
├── src/
│   ├── components/
│   │   ├── app.component.ts
│   │   ├── home.component.ts
│   │   ├── nav.component.ts
│   │   └── index.ts
│   ├── public/
│   ├── app.ts
│   └── config.ts
├── typings/
├── index.html
├── package.json
├── tsconfig.json
└── webpack.config.json
```

Comment: try import `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` as well. For example: `import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';`

Comment: It seems to doesn't works. I don't know if this is an important point but I'm not using lite-server but http-server and I'm transpiling my TS files into a specific folder.

Comment: Did you re-compile TS files to js files?

Comment: Yep, I've added my tsconfig and package.json (for the scripts) to the main post "just in case" :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple problems for your code.

#### Tell SystemJS to look in your `outDir` folder.

For example, in my `tsconfig.json`, I set `outDir: dist`. Then I have to do the following:

```
System.config({
  map: { app: 'dist'},
  packages: {        
    app: {
      format: 'register',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  }
});
```

#### Tell SystemJS to import your `bootstrap` file.

For example, if I have a file named `boot.ts`, Then I have to do:

```
 System.import('app/boot')
          .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

In you case, you should do  `System.import('app/app').then(null, console.error.bind(console));`

#### Import `ROUTER_DIRECTIVE` in nav.component

Since you are using `routerLink` which is from `ROUTER_DIRECTIVE`, you need to import it.

In your nav.component.ts `import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';`

#### Import your component from its own file, not from `index.ts`

```
//import { HomeComponent, NavComponent } from "./index";
import { HomeComponent} from "./home.component";
import { NavComponent} from "./nav.component";
```

The reason why you have

> Unexpected directive value 'undefined' on the View of component 'AppComponent'

is because your import the component from other files. I have no idea why you are doing that. But that is the problem cause this. Replace with the above code.

Comment: Thanks, now I'm using this :
`System.config({
            map: { app: 'build' },
            packages: {
                app: {
                    format: 'register',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            }
        });`
But I still get the error message

Comment: Check out SystemJS Map Api explanation https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/overview.md

Comment: Also it depends how you structure your application, the path for mapping might be different For example, my src folder is the same level of my dist folder.

Comment: I had understood this :-) my build/ folder is the same level of my src/ folder too. I'm going to add my project architecture to the main post.

Comment: I noticed that on your comment, your `app.ts` file is under src folder.

Comment: Ah okay, I though I had to import the app from build/ !
So now I'm importing it from /src/ but I get a 404 `GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/src/app 404 (Not Found)`. I have the same hierachy both in build/ and src/

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, you should keep import from `build/app`